# Not resolving dependency in vendor directory

Tags: go, vendor, glide-golang

I'm running go1.6 and am getting the follow error when running "go build" in GOPATH (/Users/bweidlich/Projects/go)

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/spf13/viper" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/spf13/viper (from $GOROOT)
/Users/bweidlich/Projects/go/src/github.com/spf13/viper (from $GOPATH)
```

Project structure:

```
bin/
glide.lock
glide.yaml
go.iml
logs/
main.go
pkg/
src/
vendor/
      github.com/
                 deckarep/gosx-notifier
                 spf13/viper
                 gizak/termui
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gizak/termui" <--- doesn't resolve
    "github.com/spf13/viper"  <--- doesn't resolve
    "log"
    "bweidlich/dash"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)
```

Comment: Why do you have `bin`, `pkg` and `src` in your project directory? Your project should be located at its import path. What is the overall structure here?

Answer (score 5):

Your `main.go` file needs to be inside a workspace (that is, inside gopath) for its dependencies to be vendored. As a test, try putting your `main.go` inside a fake path and see if the vendored deps are found:

```
$GOPATH/src/
   example.com/
     main.go
   vendor/
     github.com/
       spf13/viper/
       gizak/termui/
```

In general, you don't want to store any code in your gopath outside its root `src` directory. That is, you should echo the structure that `go get` would use when creating the directories.